# Iterate over python tuple and batch load into database table using ibm_db

Tags: python-3.x, db2

I am trying to Iterate over tuple and batch load batches of 1000 into database table using ibm_db but i am getting a strange exception error. Anyone had similar issues:

```
# establishing connection
conn = ibm_db.connect(dsn, "", "")

#making tuple from pandas df
tuple_of_tuples = tuple([tuple(x) for x in df.values])


sql2= "INSERT INTO SCHEMA.TABLE VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"

# function to break down the tuple
def chunks(l, n):
    """Yield successive n-sized chunks from l."""
    for i in range(0, len(l), n):
        yield l[i:i + n]


stmt = ibm_db.prepare(conn, sql2)

for i in chunks(tuple_of_tuples,1000):
    ibm_db.execute_many(stmt,i)
    ibm_db.commit(conn)
```

I am getting the following exception error which i am unable to troubleshoot or replicate:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-230-29555d56a7ff> in <module>
      1 stmt = ibm_db.prepare(conn, sql2)
      2 for i in chunks(tuple_of_tuples,1000):
----> 3     ibm_db.execute_many(stmt,i)
      4     ibm_db.commit(conn)

Exception:
```

Comment: @mao problem is i don't know how to do that, i am unable to show the complete exception details. I copy/pasted what i see.

Comment: Is it possible that you accidentally truncated the exception detail ?

Comment: @mao i am not sure but don't think so, i tried adding  `except BaseException as e:
    traceback.print_exc()` but  i am not seeing much more details, seeing this: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-255-412b5af8fe32>", line 5, in <module>
    ibm_db.execute_many(stmt,i)
Exception`

Comment: Have you tried catching the exception and using `ibm_db.stmt_errormsg` to retrieve the Db2 error?

Comment: @mao matching the parameter-markers s not the problem. I can load to db2 without tuple iteration and i have done this but i have a lot of rows to load so i need a manual batch load and commit after each batch load.

Comment: @mustaccio I tried that but it prints blank message, followed the concept here: [link] (https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/pl/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.swg.im.dbclient.python.doc/doc/c0054395.html)

Comment: @mao It is very strange, i tested it with different batches, it works using batches of 500 for 10,000 rows in total. When i increase the rows to load to 100,000 using same batches of 500 it breaks and gives that error.

Comment: @mao did a different experiment with batches of 100 for total of 50,000 rows. This time getting this:   `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File <ipython-input-328-412575913633>, line 5, in <module>
    ibm_db.execute_many(stmt,i)
Exception: 
 SQLCODE=-302 [CLI Driver][DB2/LINUXX8664] SQL0302N  The value of a host variable in the EXECUTE or OPEN statement is out of range for its corresponding use.  SQLSTATE=22001`

Comment: Ensure the Db2-client and ibm_db and pandas components are at the current highest fixpack number or versions. If symptoms persist, tracing may help identify the broken component.

Comment: @mao thanks, yes they are pandas is 25.1 and ibm_db is 3.0.1 and issue still persists...

Comment: @mao could using another db2 library fix the issue, any recommendations?

Comment: @MartinPetrov If there is a `db2level` command, run it and show its output. The issue might not be with the Db2-library, but instead with pandas or ibm_db or elsewhere.  Proving which component is broken will require time and skills.  This is no longer a matter for stackoverflow. If you cannot do it yourself, then Make the smallest possible test-case (standalone mvce, and give data) and open an issue on github for python/ibm_db.

Comment: Thanks @mao yes i realize this is an issue not related to the “how to” question but the how to question still remains